# Automatically Timeout RecognizerIntent

Tags: android, speech

I am playing around with Android's speech recognition and would like to be able to timeout the voice recognition intent. I am creating and starting the speech recognition intent, based on the Android API example code, and it works fine. What I would like is the ability to to automatically cancel/timeout the speech detection if there is no audio input after N milli seconds. In otherwords, listen for speech and if there is none after a short time return to the activity that started the intent. Is this possible? I looked at the documentation for RecognizerIntent and there were no extra fields for the intent for doing this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is that you set up a Post Delayed Handler. This handler will wait x seconds and then cancel the RecognizerIntent if time runs out and it is still up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adjusting the parameters in the `RecognizerIntent` such as

[EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS)

that work for both the standard sending the `Intent` and for using the `SpeechRecognizer` class directly.